# Tkinter: How to limit user to a number of functions

Tags: python, tkinter, command, turtle-graphics

I am creating a turtle program that gets the command from a text widget, then draws on a tkinter `Canvas`. But when I `eval()` that command from the `Text` widget, the program would become a Python Shell (It would even accept `print("Hello World")` as a turtle command)

Here's what I'm trying to say:

```
from tkinter import *
import turtle
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
tt = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
def moveForward (pixels):#Custom function
    tt.forward(pixels)

command = "print("Hello World")"
yourCommand = eval(command) # it would accept this as a turtle command

root.mainloop()
```

Can somebody explain to me how to limit the user input to just the custom commands created?

Comment: You could make a list of the accepted commands and check if the user input is one of them before evaluating. This probably requires some regex checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid `eval()` -- instead consider a datastructure of legal commands and treat the code that implements those commands as data.  I've implemented an example below with just the turtle module to keep it simple:

```
import turtle

commands = {
    'moveForward': lambda pixels: turtle.forward(pixels),
    'moveBackward': lambda pixels: turtle.backward(pixels),
    # ...
}

command, *arguments = input().strip().split()

if command in commands:
    (commands[command])(int(arguments[0]))

turtle.mainloop()
```

Run the program and type 'moveForward 100' and it should do what you ask, no `eval` needed.  This can get more sophisticated, with information in the dictionary on the number and types of the arguments for each command.